# Is there a guide to implementing realistic army logistics in D&D?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, realm-management, mass-combat, tactics

I just read [Grain into Gold](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/13113/Grain-Into-Gold). If you don't know it, it is a guide for creating a realistic medieval/fantasy economy.

I just wanted to know if there is any equivalent for fantasy army management, things like logistics (ravitaillement, foraging), how they did drills, how do they keep morale, some classic tactics, etc.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, this seems to be a ["shopping question"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/what-actually-is-a-shopping-question), essentially asking for a list of recommendations with no right answer. You may be able to get the information you're looking for if you ask about that information itself, rather than looking for a guide on where to find it. (You'd also have to take care not to make your question overly broad.)

Comment: @nick012000 [please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Comment: @nick012000 Do not bypass question closes. Instead work to get them into a reopenable state. Answers in comments are still unacceptable in this situation. Once it's opened with your help, your answer can be submitted for proper peer review.

Comment: @nicko12000 Helping people who ask questions that are not allowed on the site encourages them to come back and keep asking forbidden questions instead of going to [a venue better suited to their question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/3548).